# How to develop a multilingual Wordpress website in English and Arabic?

Tags: localization, internationalization, wordpress

I am going to develop a Wordpress website in English and Arabic, but I don't the know Arabic language. I am comfortable in English only.

Is there a plugin which will convert the whole website into the Arabic language?

Or is there a better approach for this problem? Clients want the website to be in English and Arabic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Translate website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820717/translate-website)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem belongs in the field of website internationalization (i18n) and localization (l10n), there are also language specific challenges for Arabic (being a language with right-to-left script), but first things first.

To implement a multilingual website in Wordpress you need to address the subject in two major areas.

- Backend

  - Support for writing and storing posts and pages in various languages;
  - Multilingual category/tag names;
  - Possible need for multilingual custom fields.
- Frontend

  - Internationalized theme which is ready to present the content as well as the frontend UI labels (e.g. "Previous Post", "Next Post", "Archives", etc.) in various languages and scripts;
  - Language negotiation, namely selecting the proper language and keeping it across pages;
  - Proper handling of locale-sensitive data; e.g. date and time, number formats, sorting, transliteration, currency names and symbols, etc;
  - i18n for SEO.

The bad news is that Wordpress doesn't support any of these out-of-the-box. The good news is that there are [plenty of plugins](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/localization) and knowledge available on this subject hence the popularity of the platform. Picking a language support plugin which suits your current and future needs is very important, because you don't want to localize 50% of your content using one plugin to find out that it doesn't support some essential requirement you recently came upon.

You definitely should consider consulting [this very concise document](http://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress) on Wordpress Codex on the subject.

I personally used [qTranslate](http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/) to get multilingual to work on the backend and database and did all the needed development directly in the theme. Back then (3 years ago) this was the best and most scalable option available on WPMU. There might be better choices out there these days. When it comes to handling locale-sensitive data and SEO, you are totally on your own since none of the plugins I know of provides a satisfactory coverage. In case you want to know more about i18n on the web, [here](http://www.w3.org/International/getting-started/) is a good starting point.

Regarding supporting Arabic (and generally right-to-left scripts) on the web, mostly it comes down to use of 'dir' attribute and some wrapping for the text. There are [these four essential](http://www.w3.org/blog/International/2013/04/22/4-new-articles-about-working-with-html-markup-in-arabic-hebrew-and-other-right-to-left-scripts/) documents by Richard Ishida of W3C which elaborate on this and gives you a very good head-start.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want an automatic translation since you can't speak/write `Arabic` yourself? If so, then something like one of these will do the trick:

- http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-translator/
- http://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/

`Polylang` lets you choose between an automatic translation and writing it yourself. There are many language plugins for `Wordpress`, so pick the one that works best for you.

Comment: Seems good to me. Have you ever tried the conversion using these plugins ?